# how can I serialize tuples as list in F#?

Tags: serialization, f#, json.net

I have a library that sends me results that include tuples. I need to process some of the data, serialize it and then it goes on its way to another system.

the tuples are ALWAYS made of 2 values but they are extremely wasteful when serialized:

```
(3, 4)
```

will serialize as:

```
{"Item1":3,"Item2":4}
```

whereas

```
[3; 4]
```

will serialize as:

```
[3,4]
```

I would like to avoid rebuilding the whole data structure and copying all the data to change this part.

Is there a way, at the serializer level, to convert the tuples into list?

the next process' parser can be easily changed to accommodate a list instead of tuples, so it seems like the best scenario.

the ugly option would be to fix the serialized string with a regex, but I would really like to avoid doing this.

Comment: There is definitely a way to fix this at the serializer level, but how to do it depends completely on what serializer you use. (Newtonsoft?, Custom?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override the default serialization behaviour by specifying your own `JsonConverter`. The following example shows a formatter that writes `int * int` tuples as two-element JSON arrays.

```
open Newtonsoft.Json

type IntIntConverter() = 
  inherit JsonConverter<int * int>()
  override x.WriteJson(writer:JsonWriter, (a:int,b:int), serializer:JsonSerializer) =
    writer.WriteStartArray()
    writer.WriteValue(a)
    writer.WriteValue(b)
    writer.WriteEndArray()

  override x.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, hasExistingValue, serializer) = 
    (0, 0)

let sample = [ (1,2); (3,4) ]
let json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sample, Formatting.None, IntIntConverter())
```

The result of running this will be `[[1,2],[3,4]]`. Note that I have not implemented the `ReadJson` method, so you cannot yet parse the tuples. This will involve some extra work, but you can look at existing `JsonConverter`s to see how this should be done.

Also note that this is for a specific tuple type containing two integers. If you need to support other tuples, you will probably need to provide several variants of the converter.